# How to resolve this npm i issue?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, core-js

Tried different solutions, but there is this issue during npm install. I've deleted the package-lock file and tried. The --force or --legacy-peer-deps option didn't help either.

```
npm WARN deprecated core-js@2.6.12: core-js@<3.4 is no longer maintained and not recommended for usage due to the number of issues. Because of the V8 engine whims, feature detection in old core-js versions could cause a slowdown up to 100x even if nothing is polyfilled. Please, upgrade your dependencies to the actual version of core-js.
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path C:\Users\HillsonGhimire\Desktop\RC\F\node_modules\node-sass
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c node scripts/build.js
npm ERR! Building: C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe C:\Users\HillsonGhimire\Desktop\RC\F\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js rebuild --verbose --libsass_ext= --libsass_cflags= --libsass_ldflags= --libsass_library=
npm ERR! gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! gyp verb cli
```

npm version: 8.3.1

node version: 16.14.0

Comment: Can you share your npm and node version?

Comment: npm version: 8.3.1 Node version: 16.14.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try these steps by installing node-sass based on your node version

```
rm -rf node_modules package-lock.json 
npm install --saveDev node-sass@6.0.1
npm install
```

Edit

Due to deprecation, changing `node-sass` to `sass` should resolve this

Comment: ```npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
While resolving: sdss-react@0.1.0
Found: react@16.14.0
node_modules/react
react@"^16.14.0" from the root project
Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer react@"^17.0.1" from react-leaflet@3.2.5
npm ERR! node_modules/react-leaflet
npm ERR!   react-leaflet@"^3.1.0" from the root project
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.```

Comment: Please try npm install -g --unsafe-perm node-sass --save and then do npm install

Comment: node-sass is the culprit here

Comment: i suspect the same

Comment: npm install returns, ``` npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR! While resolving: sdss-react@0.1.0
npm ERR! Found: react@16.14.0
npm ERR! node_modules/react
npm ERR!   react@"^16.14.0" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer react@"^17.0.1" from react-leaflet@3.2.5
npm ERR! node_modules/react-leaflet
npm ERR!   react-leaflet@"^3.1.0" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps ```

Comment: is it okay to use --force, or --legacy-peer-deps?

Comment: According to this post https://sass-lang.com/blog/libsass-is-deprecated what you can do is just replace `node-sass` in your package.json file with `sass` and then do `npm install`

Comment: Such error comes with npm v7 and above. Run npm install using ```--legacy-peer-deps```

Comment: Yes, changing the node-sass package to saas solved the issue. Thanks

Comment: Happy to help. Edited the answer. Please mark it the correct one

Answer (score 0):

Try clearing the `cache` using below code:

```
npm clean-install
```

It should work.

Comment: ```C:\Users\HillsonGhimire\Desktop\RiskChanges\riskchanges-frontend>npm clean-install
npm ERR! The `npm ci` command can only install with an existing package-lock.json or
npm ERR! npm-shrinkwrap.json with lockfileVersion >= 1. Run an install with npm@5 or
npm ERR! later to generate a package-lock.json file, then try again.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\HillsonGhimire\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2022-03-10T09_45_12_930Z-debug-0.log ``` That didn't help either..

Comment: now try `npm install`

Comment: npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! While resolving: sdss-react@0.1.0
npm ERR! Found: react@16.14.0
npm ERR! node_modules/react
npm ERR!   react@"^16.14.0" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer react@"^17.0.1" from react-leaflet@3.2.5
npm ERR! node_modules/react-leaflet
npm ERR!   react-leaflet@"^3.1.0" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
...

Comment: try running it with `--force` like this `npm install --force`